# Trouble Hiding PHP script if a DIV is present on the page

Tags: php, css, joomla

I am trying to hide the following:

```
<h1>aaa <?php echo HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi, true);?> aaa</h1>
```

If the current div is present on the page:

```
<div id="bbb">
```

I tried to use this (Didn't work):

```
<div id="bbb" <?php if (condition) { echo 'style="display:none;"; } else {
echo <h1>Find More <?php echo HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi, true);?> </h1>; } ?></div>
```

I thought that this would do what was expected but crashed the site in that area.

Sorry if this is newbie mistake or bad coding I am just starting out and couldn't find the right fit of code for this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you please post your code and clarify your question? Thanks.

Comment: The code is there, but you have to set it as code so it show properly

Comment: `'style="display:none;";` needs to be `"style="display:none;";` (single quote needs to be double quotes)

Comment: You're missing a single quote after your first echo. However, to make your life _much_ easier, look in to using a [ternary statement](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie I fixed that but still having the same issue. The site keeps crashing. It also gives me a syntax error after putting " but it doesn't seem to me that it's the issue.

Comment: `<div id="bbb" <?php if (condition) { echo "style='display:none;'"; } else { echo '<h1>Find More '. HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi, true) .'</h1>'; } ?></div>`  try this

Comment: Doesnt crash the site but the h1 is not showing

Answer (score 1):

There will be tens of different eays to code this up.  Critically, you need to ensure that:

- you are closing any opening quotes associated with your inline style declarations
- you are closing any opened html tags (`<div`)

These factors are essential to generate valid markup that will behave as you intend.  If the following doesn't work as expected, you will need to clarify/edit your question.

```
<div id="bbb"<?php echo $condition ? ' style="display:none;"' : ''; ?>>
    <?php
    if (!$condition) {
        echo '<h1>Find More ' , HTML_SOBI::getMyCategories($mySobi, true) , '</h1>';
    }
    ?>
    ...
```

Note, I reckon the second (negated) condition is probably not needed, but I'll leave it to be demonstrative.

Another consideration is to use the condition block to assign a `class` to all elements that you wish to hide.  If the condition is true, add the class like `hiddenTag` to the tags, then in your css file declare `.hiddenTag { display: none; }`.